# Date picker should appear when a button is clicked

Tags: iphone, ios

hi i am new to iphone/ipad programming .This program i will be doing for ipad so i wanted help My question is by clicking a button can date picker appear and the when the date is chosen , i want it to be stored in a text field , or is it better to insert a calender instead of date picker ?  If so how can i add a normal calender and how to code it

what changes should i do in a nib file ?? will the date will be shown in the text field ?? shouldnt there be a UITextField ??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You would create an IBAction for your button to call to show the UIDatePicker. Then implement the UIDatePicker delegate methods and set the text of your label.

In your header file:

```
-(IBAction)showDatePicker:(id)sender;
```

In your implementation file

```
 -(IBAction)showDatePicker:(id)sender
    {

    UIDatePicker* picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
                        picker.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
                        picker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

 [picker addTarget:self action:@selector(dueDateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
                        CGSize pickerSize = [picker sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
                        picker.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 250, pickerSize.width, 460);
                        picker.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                        [self.view addSubview:picker];
                        [picker release];


    }

-(void) dueDateChanged:(UIDatePicker *)sender {
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

    //self.myLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[dueDatePickerView date]];
    NSLog(@"Picked the date %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[sender date]]);
}
```

//Later when you need to, just call removeFromSuperView to remove it.

Comment: can you help me with the code , can i use a normal calender instead of date picker i want to calender/date picker to pop when i press a button .

Comment: There isn't a calendar control as part of an Apple SDK.  However there is a nice free version of a calendar called kal  http://klazuka.tumblr.com/post/315035813/kal-a-calendar-component-for-the-iphone

Comment: Just a reminder to mark the answer as correct if it is what you were looking for.  I saw that you joined SO today :)

Comment: Helpful answer, but won't it also be be necessary to recover a reference to the UIDatePicker object so that you can send the removeFromSuperView message to it when it needs dismissing. The pointer could be stored in an ivar or a tag could be set on the UIDatePicker and the reference to the object be recovered with viewWithTag:

Comment: Yes, it will and props for suggesting the use of a tag / viewWithTag:  Note I didn't add the code for adding a button either.

Comment: cool thanks i will try this in xcode and let you know ,isnt [B]UITextfield[/B] is used since the date will be stored in textField .. , can u help me out with nib file , as i am getting confused .what properties have u declared?

Answer (score 1):

```
In .h file just Create 

UIDatePicker *datePicker;

After that .m file 

// For Date
datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[_closingDateTxtFld setInputView:datePicker];
UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
[toolBar setTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(ShowSelectedDate)];
UIBarButtonItem *space = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
[toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:space,doneBtn, nil]];

[_closingDateTxtFld setInputAccessoryView:toolBar];
```

Just call this method

```
-(void)ShowSelectedDate
{
  NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
  [formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-M-dd"];
  if ([_closingDateTxtFld isFirstResponder])
   {
    _closingDateTxtFld.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",       [formatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];
    [_closingDateTxtFld resignFirstResponder];
   }
}
```